# GetElementById Alternative for more options

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, I am new to JavaScript, so I really need help with this.
I have a script, which looks like this:

```
function Change(){
    var image = document.getElementById('id-img');
    image.src = "somenotimportantlink" + document.getElementById('id-a1').title;

    var link = document.getElementById('id-a2');
    link.href="somenotimportantlink"+(document.getElementById('id-a1').title)+"/index.html";    
}
```

My problem is that there are multiple  tags that want to use this function on, but I can only use `id="id-a1"` on one tag, so I need  an alternative for getElementById, one that would allow me to use multiple tags.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you are calling `Change()`.  I suspect that you can pass in the source element from the call point which may be simpler than trying to search the DOM for the correct element.

Comment: What's the relevant HTML, what elements do you wish to retrieve?

Comment: First,i apologize, i made mistake in typing, it's actually    `"id-a1"`    , not     `"id-a2"`     that is problematic. Here is the code:    `<ul style="list-style-type:none;"> <li><a href="#" onclick="Change();" id="id-a1" title="70">Image1</a></li> <li><a href="#" onclick="Change();" id="id-a1" title="71">Image2</a></li>`

Comment: `<div><a href="link" id="id-a2"> <img alt="slika" id="id-img" src="mojaslika.jpg" style="width:200px; height: 240px;"/> </a> </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people use jQuery to do this, but you can also do it in JavaScript. The catch is, it only works on modern browsers.

---

### JavaScript Method

You would need to grab a NodeList of all the objects with a query selector and iterate over every item of that NodeList.

```
function myStuff() {
  var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
  for (var i = 0, length = nodeList.length; i < length; i++) {
     nodeList[i].href = "somenotimportantlink"+(i.title)+"/index.html";
  }
}
```

---

### jQuery Method

First you'd want to have jQuery somewhere in your HTML, I prefer using a CDN but a normal file is alright.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Once you have the jQuery file ready, you can select all classes by:

```
$('.a')
```

or if you want to select all `<a>` tags:

```
$('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's various ways in js to get elements, but if your want to use css selectors then you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".myclass");`

EDIT: sorry I goofed... use querySelectorAll

Comment: I tried that, but it still always takes only the first element with that class name, and ignores the others

Comment: use `.querySelectorAll(".myclass");` for collection

Comment: was editing my answer... can now read your Q ;) So, why are you restricted to specific ID's ?

Comment: As get the feeling your think you have to use the word id inside an id and an a if it's an a tag....

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to select the elements by id, you can use `querySelectorAll`.

- `document.querySelectorAll("[id*='id-a']")` will match all elements with an id containing `'id-a'`
- `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='id-a']")` matches all elements with an id starting with `'id-a'`.

However, I'd consider using a class instead of an id:

- `document.querySelectorAll('.someClass')`

Make sure to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` to get all the matching elements.

More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)